# How to wrap text around images in Bookdown when exporting to epub?

Tags: rmarkdown, epub, bookdown

My question is pretty straight-forward. I have read all the threads to find a solution but can still not succeed in wrapping text around images when exporting to `epub`. When exporting to `html` and `pdf` things work well. It is just `epub` that is the problem.  Whatever code I put in, I end up with a non-wrapped result like this:

[image: non-wrapped image example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question can be improved by adding a small but complete document that shows the issue, with the documentclass, packages, and one paragraph with an image. Also please show the exact command you use to compile to `epub`.

Comment: Is LaTeX involved at all when exporting bookdown to epub? Not sure this is the right place to ask this.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn and @frabkous! I have realised that it is better not to wrap text around images when exporting to `epub` but rather to only include images with full width, and here is the code to include in the `.Rmd` file to do that:                                                          

```
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="100%"} 
knitr::include_graphics("figure/photo.png")```
```

Comment: You could try using paracol, but the break points will change (with font size).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!